# Masking in SVG?

Tags: html, svg

What would be the best way to draw a circle with a slice cut out of it in svg? This would be used to overlay on top of another colored circle as a kind of masking effect.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your best bet is to use a path (kindly provided by Inkscape):

```
<path fill="red" d="m 134.73897,236.38837 a 100,92.85714 0 1 1 44.86201,86.57396 l 54.68474,-77.743 z">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="white"/>
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="black"/>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="blue" mask="url(#mask)"/>
    </svg>
```

Within the mask element, you have two circles. The first is the large circle that you want to cut from. Notice the fill is white. That means that shape will be filled.

The next circle is smaller and will be cut out of the first circle. Notice the fill is black. That means this shape will not be filled and instead be left transparent.

Now those circles are just defining the mask to be used, we still need to draw a shape to use the mask on. That's the last circle outside of the mask and defs element.

In the end, you should get a blue circle with a circular hole cut out of the center.